# Is it possible to set HTML to the output of an async function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I've made a simple function that web scrapes certain details and it works fine with only javascript. However, when I tried showing the output with html I couldn't make it work.

Here is what I have for HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <input type = "result" id = "idvalue">id here</input>
    <br>
    <button onclick = run()>click on this</button>
    <p id="result">output should go here</p>
        <script scr = "script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and here is what I have for the function run()

```
    function run(){
      const result = document.getElementById("result")
      id = idvalue.value
      (async() => {
        const profile = await getRating(id)
        const tournament = await getTournament(id)
        result.innerHTML = profile + tournament
      })();
  
    }
```

I was expecting the text below the button to change from "output should go here" to the result of the functions but the text doesn't change at all.

I'm pretty new to programming, so I am pretty sure there's something I'm missing or I'm doing it the wrong way. By the way, getRating() and getTournament() are both async functions.

Comment: I assume that you assigned `idvalue` to `document.getElementById('result')` somewhere. Otherwise, it looks alright. Do note that you won't get any error messages if anything goes wrong. Try wrap your three rows inside the async method in a try...catch statement.

Comment: Also, if `getRating()` and `getTournament()` aren't dependent of each other, I would fetch them both at the same time with `Promise.all()`. Right now, `getTournament()` waits for `getRating` to complete before trying to fetch data.

Comment: *Typo, 'result' in my first comment should be 'idvalue'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value of `<input>` by `document.getElementById("input-id").value`.

Here's an example I made: https://codepen.io/JeffreytheCoder/pen/MWXmvoo

Comment: Hi, I've realized I probably didn't provide a very good example. Here's a simplified version of the code I am trying to create. Could you tell me why this doesn't run?

Comment: `function run() {
const axios = require('axios');
 const cheerio = require('cheerio');
  const result = document.getElementById("result")
  
  const getWebsite = async() => {
    try {
    const {data} = await axios.get(
        'http://www.example.com'
      );
      output = cheerio.load(data)
      return output
    } catch (error) {
    throw error;
   }
  };

  
  (async () => {
    const promiseRes = await getWebsite()
    result.innerHTML = promiseRes
  })()
}

run()`

Comment: @Exploro could you provide a formated version like using a codepen?

Comment: Okay, here is what I have above but formatted: https://codepen.io/exploro/pen/WNyZZxr